# CONDIÇÕES IF ESTRUTURA e um if dentro de outro

Tags: if

Como fica a estrutura para colocar 2 condições no IF?

if (digitalRead(0 && 1),HIGH) ficaria assim??

E posso colocar um if dentro de outro?

por exemplo ''se o sensor1 for high subir garra, (terminou de subir) ,se sensor 2 for high desligar garra

Comment: if (digitalRead(0) == HIGH && digitalRead(1) == HIGH)  algo assim ou

Comment: if (digitalRead(0) == HIGH){ if(digitalRead(1) == HIGH){"faça algo}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deu 2 casos de 4 possíveis. Então temos o diagrama abaixo:

```
          sensor 1
        0    |    1
     +-------+-------+
s    |       |       |
e  0 | ???1  | ligar |
n    |       | garra |
s ---+-------+-------+
o    |       |       |
r  1 | desli |  ???2 |
     |   gar |       |
2    | garra |       |
     +-------+-------+
```

Não sei qual a sua intenção nesses dois casos não descritos. Talvez seja interessante não fazer nada no caso dos dois sensores desligados (caso `???1`), mas creio que um dos sensores deveria se sobressair no caso dos dois sensores ligados (caso `???2`).

Quando você for implementar isso, você precisa sim definir os quatro casos. Nem que a decisão seja não chamar nenhuma outra ação, você decidiu o que fazer com esse input.

De toda sorte, podemos transformar em uma estrutura de condições. Vou dizer aqui que `h1` é verdade caso a leitura para o sensor 1 seja `HIGH`, assim como `h2` para o sensor 2. Caso a leitura não seja `HIGH`, `h1` (ou `h2` se for o sensor 2) terá valor falso:

```
if (!h1 && !h2) {
  incognito1();
} else if (h1 && !h2) {
  ligar_garra();
} else if (!h1 && h2) {
  desligar_garra();
} else if (h1 && h2) {
  incognito2();
}
```

> O @BrunoH. sugeriu uma solução mais ou menos como essa acima no primeiro comentário dele, de toda sorte minha versão está completa

Usei aqui as funções `incognito1` para o caso `???1` e `incognito2` para `???2`. Então é só preencher o valor incógnito com a ação determinada. Se for não fazer nada, pode inclusive remover a chamada de função.

Não estou fazendo uso de nenhuma vantagem do conhecimento adquirido anteriormente. Por exemplo, o último `if` que eu coloquei é tautológico em sistemas binários: se nenhuma das outras 3 condições é verdadeira, então obrigatoriamente essa quarta vai ocorrer.

> As coisas ficam confusas quando você sai da lógica binária e remove o axioma do terceiro excluído... chamam isso de *lógica nebulosa* ou *lógica fuzzy*.

Um outro jeito de tentar usar um pouco melhor dos valores anteriormente obtidos seria fazendo uma estrutura assim:

```
se H1 && H2:
  incógnito 2
senão se H1:
  ligar garra
senão se H2:
  desligar garra
senão:
  incógnito 1
```

Isso dá exatamente o mesmo que o conjunto de `if-else-if` em sequencia anteriormente apresentado. Por quê?

1. Se a primeira condição for falsa, então pelo menos um dos sensores não está fornecendo sinal `HIGH`
2. A segunda e a terceira comparação do são executadas no caso de pelo menos um sensor não retornar `HIGH`, então agora elas implicam que se uma for verdadeira, a outra é necessariamente falsa
   (mas não há implicação de uma ser falsa, a outra é verdadeira, a contra-positiva não se sustenta)
3. Caso nenhuma das três condições acima for verdade, então isso implica que os dois sinais recebidos dos sensores não são `HIGH`

Ou então eu poderia aninhar os `if`s um dentro do outro:

```
if (h1) {
  if (h2) {
    incognito2();
  } else {
    liga_garra();
  }
} else {
  if (h2) {
    desliga_garra();
  } else {
    incognito2();
  }
}
```

> O @BrunoH. sugeriu uma solução mais ou menos como essa acima no segundo comentário dele, de toda sorte minha versão está completa

Eu às vezes não sou exatamente um cara que segue padrões de projeto/de codificação, então nesse caso é bem capaz de eu ir por outro lado... Você não pôs em qual linguagem está programando isso, então a minha solução só faz sentido caso ela tenha suporte a estrutura de fluxo `switch`, ou então você poderia destrinchar em uma sequência de `if-else-if`s para simular o `switch`.

Como estamos lidando com sinais, podemos transformá-los em uma string de bits. Por exemplo, considerando `h2,h1` em *big-endian*, caso o sensor 2 estivesse em `HIGH` e o 1 em outro valor, eu obteria a sequência de bits `10`, o que equivale ao número `2` em base decimal. Então, eu faria um `switch` desse número obtido.

A operação ao todo é deslocar o bit recebido de `h2` para uma casa mais significativa de juntar com o bit recebido em `h1`. Em C, considerando que o valor "verdade" seja um único bit com valor de 1, especificamente o bit menos significativo significativo:

```
h2 << 1 | h1
```

- `h2 << 1`: estou deslocando os bits de `h2` para uma posição mais significativa
- `| h1` operador do `ou` bit-a-bit juntando o resultado anterior com `h1`; nesse caso `10 | 01` resulta em `11` e `00 | 01` resulta em `01`

Então, sobre essa conta, colocaria um `switch` e trataria os 4 casos. O caso em `default` do `switch` entretanto precisa ser tratado de maneira separada (portanto `incognito3`).

```
switch (h2 << 1 | h1) {
case 0:
  incognito1();
  break;
case 1:
  ligar_garra();
  break;
case 2:
  desligar_garra();
  break;
case 3:
  incognito2();
  break;
default:
  incognito3();
}
```

## Como não fazer

Um exemplo muito simples de fazer errado:

```
if (h1) {
  ligar_garra();
}
if (h2) {
  desligar_garra();
}
```

Por que não fazer assim?

Simples. Imagina que chamar `ligar_garra` e `deslgar_garra` vão fazer comunicação imediata com uma peça de hardware muito sensível chamada `garra`. Aqui, você está em poucos microssegundos enviando dois comandos distintos e contraditórios para ela. Dependendo da sensibilidade do hardware, você pode inclusive gerar uma pane nele. É como se você mandasse o carro acelerar para frente e dar a ré ao mesmo tempo... pode até quebrar o motor se você conseguir essa proeza.